# Installing pandas, python34?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

[image]I am trying to install pandas and I keep getting an error

```
Microsoft visual c++ 10.0 is required?
```

Is it really necessary to have it ? and how can I have it?

when I try to upgrade pip from 9 to 18, it says I should do it through python, how is that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to upgrade your pip from version 9 to version 18.

If you have virtual environment. Then first activate your virtualenv or else if you have global python installed. They simply type the following command

> pip install --upgrade pip

This will show the following output

```
(p_env) ➜  python_playground git:(master) ✗ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 1.4MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

Once your pip is upgraded. Then type the following command to install `pandas`

> pip install pandas

Comment: I was trying for ages to upgrade pip but as you see from the picture i attached now, it always give me error. and regarding the pandas, it is the same. I am not sure what to  do. i tried all different solution provided even in the link they added to my question as duplicated but it doesnt work

Comment: @Rory What if you try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: it says python is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: could you add python to the environment by following this https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/?

Comment: I did that, and I used the command you provided and it said that : I must give at least one requirement to install